# Sliding Boxes in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I only recently started learning about the technologies involved in making web pages. A doubt that occurred to me is the sliding or the appearance of small boxes after a click. If I am being unclear an example can be found in the codecedemy.com website (log-out button) or the sign-out button in Gmail or Yahoo. The behavior is that once a link is clicked a small box opens-up giving more options and it doesn't disappear untill the user clicks else where.

I learnt about writing sliding menus in javascript (using tables and slide-down animation) and I guess this could be done similarly. is this true? if not how else?

Comment: Also known as `modal box`, `model window`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sliding Boxes in a page you mentioned is also known as `model window` or `model box`

Model window is mainly used to get the **`user attention`**. According to the admin setting it will Slide In, Fade In... As you mentioned it could be done using `Javascript`.

Here is a Wikipedia article about `model window`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window